# Vuefire Nuxt 3 SSR - useCurrentUser null on server-side

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js, nuxt3, vuefire

In my Nuxt 3 app I have a global auth middleware that looks like so:

```js
// middleware/auth.global.ts
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, from) => {
  /**
   * @link: https://v3.vuefire.vuejs.org/nuxt/auth.html#:~:text=//%20middleware/auth.ts
   */

  const user = await getCurrentUser();
  const publicPages = ["/login", "/register", "/thank-you", "/verify"];

  if (!user && !publicPages.includes(to.path)) {
    return navigateTo({
      path: "/login",
      query: {
        redirect: to.fullPath,
      },
    });
  }
});
```

This middleware causes me however to be redirected to the `login` page after a full reload as `await getCurrentUser()` appears to be `null` on the server-side.

And obviously, once redirected, I am stuck there as typing in `/my-authed-page/` in the URL is a effectively a server request.

I also tried to patch this by forcing a redirection to `/my-authed-page/` if the user is authenticated and on the login, but a) this is causing other issues and b) this is a "patch".

The docs read:

> Nuxt VueFire integrates with Firebase Authentication module to automatically synchronize the current user state on the server and the client

Isn't this supposed to mean that `getCurrentUser()` should be available on the server too after full reload and therefore not lead to this issue?

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Session cookies are the answer to the question, as per the discussion here: https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire/discussions/1404.

So:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // ...
  vuefire: {
    // ensures the auth module is enabled
    auth: {
      enabled: true
      // enables the sessionCookie
      sessionCookie: true
    },
  },
})
```